# Azure Storage private container blob to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, azure-storage

I'm running around in circles trying to work out the code to download a file from an Azure Storage private container into a MemoryStream.

I have this so far...

```
StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(*my StorageAccountName*, *my StorageAccountAccessKey*);
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true);

Uri blobUri = new Uri(featureFile.URL);
CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(blobUri);

MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();  
blob.DownloadToStream(mem);
```

It errors on the last line with...

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

However, it will work without error when the container is not private.

Any help much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(*my StorageAccountName*, *my StorageAccountAccessKey*);
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true);

Uri blobUri = new Uri(featureFile.URL);
CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(blobUri, storageCredentials);//added storageCredentials

MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();  
blob.DownloadToStream(mem);
```

Since the container has `Private` ACL, the request needs to be authenticated. Using [`this`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj682568.aspx) constructor of [`CloudBlockBlob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj682568.aspx) takes care of that.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I was just missing that extra parameter. It's working without error now.